# How to connect Minecraft Login Servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking, minecraft-launcher

```
MAC

java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Cannot normally access minecraft.net. I have to use freemybrowser vpn, and it works fine.

When I open up my Minecraft launcher, i cannot connect to the authentication servers. I am not sure if a firewall is blocking, but I think it is. I am using my university computer.

I have tried Hamachi and researched other stuff on the web, but I can't find anything that works. I thought about downloading Minecraft files on my windows computer (using a mac bootcamp) and transferrin it onto my usb and then playing on my unviersity comp, but i'm not sure that will work.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to connect to either a VPN, or a proxy like TOR. You can setup proxies on Java with this tutorial https://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml

> 1. In the Java Control Panel, under the General tab, click on Network Settings.
> 2. Select the Use Browser Settings checkbox.
> 3. Click OK to save your changes.

To add, click on advanced to configure SOCKS proxy (as TOR is a SOCKS proxy)

[image]

You can find the Java control panel on an OS X in **System Preferences** > **Java Control Panel**

You can port-forward, and host a server at home, or take a laptop or something and make a TOR server on it, then connect.